# UIViewControllers in UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a design question. I have a scroll view that I want to use as a means of navigation. I.e. the user can slide between screens. At present, I am creating view controllers and putting their views directly on the scroll view:

```
aViewController.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,200);    
[self.myScrollView addSubview:[aViewController view]]
```

Etc, for all 3 view controllers.

I know this isn't best practice. But I can't think of any other way of doing it. Ideally I would like to get the same behaviour as a navigation controller except the fact that I'll be using a scroll view. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be aware that this breaks certain `UIViewController` behaviors because these child view controllers do not get informed about interface rotation events and their `viewWill/Did(Dis)Appear:` methods will not work.

The alternative (until iOS 4.x at least) is to not use `UIViewController` subclasses for these subviews. You could easily create your own custom controller class (derived from `NSObject`) to manage a child view.

It's debatable whether that approach makes it easier overall, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you're trying to achieve is something similar to this app?

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fanhattan-for-ipad/id436928538?mt=8

This app works in the same manner, using a scroll view for navigation. You can analyze that app, you'd get some ideas from it, i'm sure.